# PSCollectionView's delegate not fire

Tags: ios, objective-c

I followed PSCollectionView's usage on [Github](https://github.com/ptshih/PSCollectionView).

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  self.collectionView = [[PSCollectionView alloc] init];
  self.collectionView.collectionViewDataSource = self;
  self.collectionView.collectionViewDelegate = self;
  self.collectionView.numColsPortrait = 2;

  [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
  [self.collectionView reloadData]; // If i don't call this my console will be empty.
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInCollectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView 
{
  NSLog(@"num rows");
  return 2;
}
- (PSCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView cellForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
  NSLog(@"cell for row");
  return nil;
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView heightForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
  NSLog(@"height for row");
  return 0.0;
}
```

My console was empty. But when I called [collectionView reloadData], here is the result:

```
num rows
height for row
height for row
num rows
```

I have no idea why "cell for row" is not printed out.

Any hint or suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Have you added the following datasource in .h file - <PSUICollectionViewDataSource> ?

Comment: I've added these in .h file: <PSCollectionViewDataSource, PSCollectionViewDelegate>

Comment: Have you linked in .xib file?

Comment: Or just set this Object - PSUICollectionView *collectionView; // Alloc and init etc.. collectionView.dataSource = self;
  collectionView.delegate = self;

Comment: Yeah I set it's data source and delegate: self.collectionView.collectionViewDataSource = self;
self.collectionView.collectionViewDelegate = self;

Comment: Can you show the code where you have created collectionView object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can make it works!

You must set the PSCollectionView instance's frame.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you have typo , it's not `ViewDidLoad()` it's `viewDidLoad()`, so your `ViewDidLoad()` normally never gets called. So, you're not able to set your delegate and datasource properly.

Comment: Sorry, I have typo in question not in my code. The - (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInCollectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView and - (CGFloat)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView heightForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index are called.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

`[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];`

at the end of your viewDidLoad.

Usually you need to tell your collectionView what Cells/Views to use.

Comment: In this case, self.collectionView is a PSCollectionView not a UICollectionView. It does not have registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier method.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant PSTCollectionView. My bad.