# PSCollectionView call delegate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, delegates

In my app I will use the PSCollectionView, but it doesn't call the delegate method. I made so:

1. I read a JSON file
2. I parse this JSON to obtain name and image url
3. I connect the device to the image url to obtain width and height with the code you find at the end of this question

After this operation I need to call delegate method to obtain number of PSCollectionViewCell, to define the height of each cell and to fill the cell with image and name.
I implemented the delegate method, but it doesn't execute them. I guess my problem is because that when it want to create and define the characteristic of the cell the array who contains the information to fill the cell is still empty. How I can solve this?

CODE:

```
- (void) loadImageFromWeb:(NSString *)urlImg forName:(NSString*)name {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlImg];
    //NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    NSString *authCredentials =@"reply:reply";
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",[authCredentials base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:0]];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                               NSData * data,
                                               NSError * error) {
                               if (!error){
                                   image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                   imageWidth = image.size.width;
                                   imageHeight = image.size.height;
                                   imgWidth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", imageWidth];
                                   imgHeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", imageHeight];
                                   self.dictWithDataForPSCollectionView = @{@"title": name,
                                                                            @"width": imgWidth,
                                                                            @"height": imgHeight};
                                   [self.arrayWithData addObject:self.dictWithDataForPSCollectionView];
                                   NSLog(@"DATA ARRAY: %@", self.arrayWithData);
                               } else {
                                   NSLog(@"ERRORE: %@", error);
                               }

                           }];
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: POssible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476698/pscollectionviews-delegate-not-fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that the delegate and the datasourse is called before that you set the array for fix your issue you have to reload the data when you set you array like that:

```
-(void)setArrayWithData:(NSArray *)arrayWithData{

    if(_arrayWithData != arrayWithData){
       _arrayWithData = arrayWithData;
    }

    [_yourCollectionView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you connect the collectionview to your view controller by either doing myCollectionView.delegate = self;

OR

Control drag in interface builder from collectionview to view controller

Comment: It's a PSCollectionView not a simply CollectionView [here you find the code](https://github.com/ptshih/PSCollectionView)

Comment: Whatever collection view this is, it is a subclass of a regular collection view. You still need to link up the delegate