# PSCollectionView doesn't not execute the cellForRowAtIndex

Tags: ios, delegates, uicollectionview

In my app I'm using [PSCollectionView](https://github.com/ptshih/PSCollectionView) to have a custom collection view. I've all data ready to create the view, but when I execute the code it doesn't call the method

```
- (PSCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView cellForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index`
```

I searched on stackoverflow and I see that another person has the same problem ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476698/pscollectionviews-delegate-not-fire)), but I'm not understanding how he has solved, so I decided to write a question to understand how to call this method. I hope there are someone that can help me to find a way to solve this issue.

UPDATE:

Here's the `viewDidLoad`code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.navBar.title = self.category;
    NSString *stringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://54.204.6.246/magento8/api/rest/products/?category_id=%d", self.categoryId];
    [self sendRequestToURL:stringUrl withMethod:@"GET"];
    // Inizio sezione di codice per la creazione della PSCOLLECTIONVIEW
    psView = [[PSCollectionView alloc]init];
    // Imposto il delegato per la gestione della scrollView
    psView.delegate = self;
    // Imposto il delegato per la collection view
    psView.collectionViewDelegate = self;
    // Imposto il delegato per il data source della collection view
    psView.collectionViewDataSource = self;

    psView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    // Controllo il tipo di device e a seconda del dispositivo trovato creo le colonne e le righe
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]) {
        psView.numColsPortrait = 2;
        psView.numColsLandscape = 4;
    } else {
        psView.numColsPortrait = 2;
        psView.numColsLandscape = 4;
    }

    // Aggiungo la vista appena creata
    [self.view addSubview:psView];
}
```

And here's the delegate code:

```
#pragma mark - PSCollection Delegate e Data Source

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInCollectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView {
    return [self.arrayWithData count];
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView heightForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
//    NSDictionary *item = [self.arrayWithData objectAtIndex:index];
//    
//    return [ProductViewCell heightForViewWithObject:item inColumnWidth:psView.colWidth];
    return 100.0f;
}

- (PSCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView cellForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    ProductViewCell *cell = (ProductViewCell *)[psView dequeueReusableViewForClass:nil];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[ProductViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }
    cell.labelName.text = [[self.arrayWithData objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[self.arrayWithData objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"url"]];

    [cell.productImage setImageWithURL:url
                             completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

                                 //[[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] imageCache] removeImageForKey:yacht.thumbnail fromDisk:NO];
                                 [[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] imageCache] clearMemory];


                             }];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have to be a delegate problem. Looking @ Github example of use:

```
self.collectionView = [[PSCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.collectionView.delegate = self; // This is for UIScrollViewDelegate
self.collectionView.collectionViewDelegate = self;
self.collectionView.collectionViewDataSource = self;
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.collectionView.autoresizingMask = ~UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

So you have to set delegate 3 times. Do you have assign all of them?

And the other thing. Base on docs in Github:

```
- (Class)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView cellClassForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [PSCollectionViewCell class];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInCollectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 0;
}

- (UIView *)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView cellForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView heightForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return 0.0;
}
```

Check if all other method is being called. Check output of `numberOfRowsInCollectionView` because if you are return `0` in this method your `cellForRowAtIntex:` will never be called.

**EDIT**
Try changing line:

```
psView = [[PSCollectionView alloc]init];
```

To:

```
psView = [[PSCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

This is should make you full screen `PSCollectionView`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I set all delegate as is written in Git documentation, then I check if the number of row and when I write a `NSLog` I saw that it returns 2, no idea about why it doesn't call the `- (PSCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView cellForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index`. The other 2 delegate methods are called.

The other person who has the same problem says that I should set the PSCollectionView instance's frame, but how I can do that?

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I see the frame! Now I've to set the correct information in this cells.

Comment: I guess I've the same problem to insert the data in this cell. If you look at my code in my question, you can see that when I create the cell I make it so: `cell = [[ProductViewCell alloc]initWithFrameCGRectZero];`. For now I see the collection view with only the frame and without content, how I can insert the content in this farme?

Comment: Content of the cell is generated by `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: solved thank you: it was the same problem I've to set a dimension and a position of the label and image view :)

Comment: @kuba i am new to iOS developing, i want to use PSCollectionview but i didn't find any sample code for that did you have it? did you have any sample project that have PSCollectionview?

Comment: @PRJ no it's gone. The github is 2 years old now. You shouldn't use it anymore.

Comment: @Kuba ok thanks, what you would suggest as alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to set dataSource for you collectionView to class where you implement cellForRowAtIndex, for example:

```
collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: It's not an unusual collection view, go to the git site and look to the read me. I have not any things on my storyboard/xib, and I set all the delegate I need. I will update my question to show you